# Force HTTPS for app deployed in google app engine

Tags: https, google-app-engine-python

If an application developed to support only HTTP. What configuration we should do in google app engine, that it force developer to have HTTPS support. We can add an entry(for handler) in "app.yaml", but in order to redirection. Just want to know anything else we can do to prevent such thing(in short should work with HTTPS only). Probably we can do something from ingress/loadbalancer/ssl etc but that's looks paid and don't want that currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set `secure: always` in app.yaml for your route handlers. Any call to your app from `http` will automatically get redirected to `https`

Comment: Hello, Thanks, but is it possible to block HTTP completely and throw 403. Any app engine setting(firewall) through which we can achieve this?

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible (and the question has been asked multiple times). Other option is to write it within your code. For example, if your code was in python + flask, write something in ```before_request``` to check for ```http``` and return a ```403```

Comment: agree, but one of the requirements was stating how without using handler or modifying the code is it possible to block. I think that's not possible. Only redirection we can do.

Comment: actually here in docs they talk about INGRESS, is it really possible? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/application-security#:~:text=The%20Google%20Cloud%20Web%20Security,and%20event%20handlers%20as%20possible.

Comment: I think the above is more on "network ingress controls" and you deploy app by writing function in "google cloud function"

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble putting a whole site over HTTPS, so searching I found a solution that worked for me:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref

what it says is that you can change your app.yaml file and place in the handlers

```
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```